# Creating tr value filter

Tags: php, html

I creating filer for website data. I have created value attribute for `<tr>`which means that the row belongs for specific company. And now i want to make that table would show rows depending which value i will choose. And i really dont have idea how to do that. $currentCompany is that value number of company id. Here is my script:

```
if($row["type"] != "Staff Comment")
{

    print("<tr value=". $currentCompany ." style='height:25px;'>\n");
        for ($loop = 0; $loop < count($fields["headings"]); $loop++) {

            print("<td bgcolor='white' align=" . $fields["aligns"][$loop] . ">\n");

            //translate some information, some not
            if ($fields["headings"][$loop] == "Status") {
            print($AppUI->_(format_field($row[$fields["columns"][$loop]], $fields["types"][$loop], $row[$fields["columns"][0]])) . "\n");
        }
        else {
            print(format_field($row[$fields["columns"][$loop]], $fields["types"][$loop], $row[$fields["columns"][0]]) . "\n");

        }
            print("</td>\n");
        //print("<tr>" . var_dump($fields) ."</tr>\n");

        }
    print("</tr>\n");
```

And here is how it looks like in website:
[image]

Hope you can help me guys. For example if i would choose value 25 it would print all tr which has that value.

Comment: How the filter is called with Javascript, Ajax or PHP ?

Comment: Better would be with php but can be with javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to hide rows, or just not print them? If hide - You have to use JS - PHP cannot modify site dynamically. If just don't print them - use simple if, and possibly You want to pass this information via simple form and POST request.
Create form, which action point to Your script, and have text field where you can specify which company have to be shown. Then, in Your code something like this:

```
 if($currentCompany == $_POST['company'])
 {
    print("<tr value=". $currentCompany ." style='height:25px;'>\n");
    //More code....
 }
```

With JS it will be more complicated - but easy, too. It will have to be done in this way:

1. Get all TR's
2. Check every TR value. If value not corresponds to Your needs - add "display: none" CSS attribute.

Concrete JS implementation depends on way you want to code in JS - pure JS, jQuery, other JS framework.